# Is there a way to link Save Results (for an insert DML operation) back to sObjects?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

### Background

I have a list of sObjects I need to insert, but I must first check if the insert will be successful. So, I'm setting a database save point before performing the insert and checking the save results (for the insert statement). Because, I don't want to process if any errors occurred, if there were any errors in the insert results, the database is rolled back to the save point.

### Problem & Question

I need to collect the errors for each save (insert) result and associate each error to the specific sObject record that caused the error. According to the documentation [Save results](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_insert.htm#apex_saveresult) contain a list of errors, the Salesforce ID of the record inserted (if successful), and a success indicator (boolean).

**How do I associate the Save Result to the original sObject record inserted?**

### Code/Example

Here's an example I put together that demonstrates the concept. The example is flawed, in that the `InsertResults` don't always match the `sObjectsToInsert`. It's not exactly the code I'm using in my custom class, but it uses the same logic.

```
Map<Id,sObject> sObjectsToInsert; // this variable is set previously in the code
List<Database.SaveResult> InsertResults;

Map<String,sObject> ErrorMessages = new Map<String,sObject>();

System.SavePoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();

// 2nd parameter must be false to get all errors, if there are errors
//   (allow partial successes)
InsertResults = Database.insert(sObjectsToInsert.values(), false); 

for(Integer i=0; i < InsertResults.size(); i++)
{
  // This method does not guarantee the save result (ir) matches the sObject
  //   I need to make sure the insert result matches
  Database.SaveResult ir = InsertResults[i];
  sObject s = sObjectsToInsert.values()[i]; 

  String em = null; // error message
  Integer e = 0; // errors

  if(!ir.isSuccess())
  {
    system.debug('Not Successful');
    e++;

    for(Database.Error dbe : ir.getErrors()) { em += dbe.getMessage()+' '; }
    ErrorMessages.put(em, s);
  }
}

if(e > 0)
{
  database.rollback(sp);

  // log all errors in the ErrorMessages Map
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your comment says the `SaveResult` list is not guaranteed to be in order, but I believe that it is. I've used this technique for years and have never had an issue.

Comment: I thought so too (+1 for that), but I'm having an unexplained issue matching them up, and I'm fairly sure they're not matching.

Comment: After I collect the errors, I try to insert the records that would have succeeded, but when I attempt to insert the records that would succeed, I get the same error that was caught earlier. In this particular instance, I have 6 records that I'm trying to insert, 3 succeed, 3 error. I try to insert the 3 that would succeed, and receive the same error recorded on the 3 that errored earlier. I suppose it's possible that they're in the correct order, but I don't know how else to explain what I'm seeing.

Comment: If I'm inserting map values (`Database.insert(sObjectsToInsert.values(), false);`) would that cause the values to be mismatched?

Comment: Yes.. the map does not guarantee order.